# Dropzone custom config typeError on thumb preview

Tags: dropzone.js

When using the following dropzone config I get an error but only when the thumbnail is generated.

```
Error: TypeError: file.acceptDimensions is not a function
Source File: .../jquery.js?v=3 line 2 > eval
Line: 66

In firebug I see at line 70 the error is at Emitter.prototype.off = function(event, fn) {
```

Standard setup works fine. Can anybody spot the issue and fix my drop out zone!

```
var uploader = new Dropzone('#droparea', {  
previewTemplate: previewTemplate,               // preview Template
previewsContainer: "#av-dz-preview",            // container Holding html5 image previews
url: upload_url,
maxFiles:1,                                     // number of files
maxFilesize: 4,                                 // in MB
acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg',       // allowed image types don't use image/*
autoQueue: false,                               // make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
addRemoveLinks: false,                          // show remove links bool
thumbnailHeight:40,                             // ds thumb preview width in px (int)
thumbnailWidth: 40,                             // dz thumb preview height in px (int)
createImageThumbnails: true,                    // show thumbnails bool
clickable: "#add-file",                         // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
init: function() {
this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
      if (file.width < thumbW || file.height < thumbH) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      }
      else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() { done("Image is too small"); };
  }, });
```

Comment: It appears that if the file status from the internal validation methods, maxFilesize or acceptedFiles gets set to 'error' then trying to check the file size in the thumbnail method causes the error. To get around this check the file status first by adding if(file.status !== 'error') { check file sizes }. Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: thanks, this helped :)